# Socket.io room feature to create game tables on demand

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using JS and socket.io to make a multiplayer game.

The game player limit is ranging from 2-5.

What I want to achieve is :

1: On the client browser there is a dropdown list displaying all the game table  names and its max player limit. A player can join any room by click on it.

2: Once the table player limit is reached, the room cannot be joined again.

3:players in each room can play their own game, chat in their own channel without being distracted.

In my current design there is a static room object and in the room project there is an array of pre-created tables object. The table object has many of the properties and methods that a game would need.

Server side room and table object:

```
function Room(name) {  
this.players = [];
this.tables = [];
};

function Table(tableID){  
this.id = tableID;
this.players = [];
this.maxPlayerLimit = 4;
};
```

I can pre-created amount number of tables and push these tables object to room's tables array.

```
Room.prototype.createTables = function(amount) {
var tableList = [];
for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++){
    var table = new Table(i+1);
    table.setName("Table" + (i + 1));
    tableList.push(table);
}
return tableList;
};
```

client side when they click on the dropdown:

The drop down looks like https://jsfiddle.net/1oyy98uo/

`socket.emit("connectToTable", {tableID:TableID,tableName: tableName,limit:limit});` //these info is based on their table selection in the dropdown

When a player connect to server I push them to the static room player array.

when they choose a table, I do

```
socket.on('connectToTable',function(data) {
  var player = room.player(socket.id)// (room method to get the socket player)
  var table = room.table(data.tableID); //(room method to get the table)
  table.Name(data.tableName)//(table method to set name)
  table.maxPlayerLimit = Number(data.limit)
  if (tableisAvailable){
   table.join(player)//table method to add player to its list
  if(table.players.length===maxPlayerlimit){
   init the game
   }else{
   client.emit("table is full")//then the client would know to go elsewhere
   }
   }
   })
```

My design fulfills all the goals. but it is done in such a hard-coded way. **The pre-created table might be too many or too little.** The only way to solve this with my current design is to create more rooms than expected.

I am not sure if I should still stick with my current design or socket.io room feature can provide a better solution. (creating game tables on demand)

But there is a flaw in the on-demand scenario:

players make requests to join a room(table), once the requests reach to a certain limit (like 4) the server will join these players. This way the server will only create as many rooms(tables) as necessary. **But these queued-up players are random players,  they may not necessarily want to play with each other. If players want to play with their friends, this will be a problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With the Socket.io room feature, is there a more dynamic way or better way to create rooms(in my case is game tables) with different player limit ON DEMAND?

socket.io rooms are completely dynamic.  You don't "create a room".  Instead, you just join a socket to a room and that room will be automatically created.  Similarly, you don't remove removes either.  When the last socket leaves a room, the room just disappears.

So, if you use socket.io rooms instead of your Tables, then their creation will be entirely on demand.  You can iterate the rooms in service at any time.  You can iterate the sockets in a room at any time.  You can add or remove a socket from a room at any time.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? I cannot really use socket.io room to replace my tables, because I need the table properties and method for the game play. I am thinking when clients create a room, they need to be able to set the number limit, and the limit is the same as the table player limit inside the room. So when a 2 player room is full, the server will  create another 2 player room when is requested? But in this way it is hard to reflect the room names in the client's' browser.

Comment: @jindsay - I guess I no longer understand what your question is asking.  You have `Table` and `Room` objects and you don't want to get rid of them.  So, what is the actual question?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I want to achieve 1: display all the pre-created table names on the client browser, a client would go to whichever room they click on. (and their friends would know which table to join) 2: each table has player limit, which I can set in my table object. when the limit reached, players will not be able to join.  My current design works fine on it. But then my concern is if the player number is bigger than the pre-created room can accommodate, that would be a problem. I can however pre-created more rooms, but it would not seem the best way..

Comment: @jindsay - That logic would all happen in code you don't show us where you decide what to do when a player wants to join a room.  You would just have to decide which existing tables had space for a new player and assign them or if no existing tables had room, then you'd see if the room has space for a new table and, if so,  you'd create a new table.  Similarly when a player leaves a table, you'd decide whether you should remove an empty table.  I don't know what you're asking us for.  You don't show any of the relevant code for assigning players to a table.  That's where this would go.